# Heroku. Should I use a Web or Worker Process?

Tags: node.js, heroku, https

Im very new in use heroku and I dont know when to use web dynos or workers. My code do http requests and downlaods archives from an external site. What I want to know if it has to be a worker or a web dyno

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require("fs");
const tiktok = require("tiktok-scraper");
var link

(async () => {
  try {
      const posts = await tiktok.user('doarda', { number: 100 });
      link = posts.collector[0].videoUrl
  

const optionsRequest = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "pt-BR,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    
  }
}


  const file = fs.createWriteStream(posts.collector[0].id +".mp4");
  const request = await https.get(link,optionsRequest, function(response) {
  
  response.pipe(file)
});
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a Web Dyno if your application is going to accept (incoming) HTTP requests. It will bind a given port ($PORT env variable) when it starts and the URL would be something like `myapp.herokuapp.com`

On the other hand the Worker does not require connectivity: it is typically a backend process that can perform some logic. Notice you can still initiate outgoing connection from the worker (ie connect to cloud service or web sites).

Also note that web processes are given their requests **through** heroku's dyno manager, meaning that your web process(in the free tier) will run only when it has active requests

On the other hand worker processes run until you stop them (either with the cli or the website)

Comment: so I tried to deploy this code to heroku, on a web dyno but it cannot downlaod the file.. But he file when I run this locally is correct downloaded